# how to prevent component be unmounted even if the route changes with React-router 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want my certain component not to unmount when changing the route
because every time it unmounts and mounts, something changes in it.
It should mount just once when I click the route for it and should not re-render. If second time it mounts when I go to another page and come back, it will show different thing on the screen (because it depends from a random number variable) which is not wanted.
How to solve this?

here is my code.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Start />} />
  <Route path='/questions' element={<SharedLayoutQuestions />}>
    <Route index element={<SharedLayoutQuestions firstQuestion={true} />} />
    <Route path='/questions/:questionIndex' element={<SingleQuestion />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

I want my `SharedLayoutQuestions` and `SingleQuestion` components not to unmount when the page changes in the questions path.

Comment: I believe this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) your *attempted solution* is to prevent component unmounting when the *root problem* is actually state persistence. Is it possible to store the "random variables" outside the component such as a context/state above the router or in local storage?

Comment: `SingleQuestion` will unmount when the path `"/questions/:questionIndex"` no longer matches. What exactly is the use case you are trying to solve for here? Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so we've more complete context what the code is doing?

Comment: it is a quiz questions. random number variable decides in which position should the right answer appear. if i keep it in context or state and pass it down in all questions the right answer will be in the same position. i need just to pretend it from unmounting.

Comment: You should [edit] the post to include a better and more complete [mcve] so we can see what else is going on with your app code. I agree with @Undo that this smells like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

In a typical React application using React Router, navigating to different routes will cause the components associated with the previous route to unmount, while the components associated with the new route will mount. This cannot be changed.

However, if the component is rendered outside of the `<Switch>` or `<Route>` components, it will remain mounted even when navigating to a different route.

Additionally, you could move the "random number variable" to the state above the routes and pass that value down to the components rendered in your routes (when/if they get re-rendered, the data will be the same)

Comment: i read an answer about this, but it was an older version of react router where it was possible to use <Route> outside of <Routes>. but now it gives an error in version 6. there is no switch in v6 also.

Comment: it is a quiz questions project. random number variable decides in which position should the right answer appear. if i keep it in context or state and pass it down in all questions the right answer will be in the same position. i need just to pretend it from unmounting.